# How to setup F3 with XAMPP locally?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, fat-free-framework

I am trying to run a Fat Free PHP project locally with XAMPP from C:\xampp\htdocs\abc
My problem is none of my css, images, or links work. I added an .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /abc/index.php [L,QSA]
```

It seems to have helped somewhat in that my index.php loads but none of the css nor images load. Also, when I click any links I get 404s, and the url does not route to my `/abc` directory.

I have tried countless RewriteRules and RewriteConds with no luck.

Also, everything works fine in production so I would like to not change the structure.

Any help on the would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: +1 I know this could be resolved with an HTML `<base href="">` tag, but I too am curious if there is a pure htaccess solution.

Comment: If `<base href="/abc/">` can fix it then there is no need to come up with rewrite magic.

Comment: Sadly this is not working for me. It is not changing the request URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule (.+\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g|css))$ /abc/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule .* /abc/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having an issue with paths.

From your comments, I assume that your assets and links are written like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.css" />
<img src="/mypic.png"/>
<a href="/what/ever.html">click</a>
```

Those links are *absolute* (notice the leading `/`). Which means they are pointing to the server root, so:

- `bootstrap.css` resolves to `myserver.tld/bootstrap.css`
- `mypic.png` resolves to `myserver.tld/mypic.png`
- etc.

They are working on your production website probably because the project is hosted on the server root.

But on your local server, everything is shifted from `/` to `/abc/` which lead to wrong link resolution. So you have two solutions:

**Solution 1**

Preprend all your links with [BASE](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#BASE). If you're using the framework template engine, that would give:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ @BASE }}/bootstrap.css" />
<img src="{{ @BASE }}/mypic.png"/>
<a href="{{ @BASE }}/what/ever.html">click</a>
```

**Solution 2**

Inform the browser that all links should be resolved relatively to `/abc/` by adding the `<base>` tag inside your `<head>` section:

```
<base href="http://myserver.tld/abc/">
```

or

```
<base href="/abc/">
```

*NB: the trailing slash is important. The whole string is treated as a prefix for all links.*

**Remark**

Those 2 solutions are not 100% equivalent, since the 2nd solution impacts anchor links. Indeed, `<a href="#foo">` points to:

- the current page with the first solution
- the base URI with the second solution (i.e `/abc/#foo`)

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to create a VirtualHost. It impacts other Apache config files, but I assume you just want to recreate the environment locally (where you have a full autonomy and power to customize it), so the code of the application will not need to be changed.

Open Windows `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in any text editor, but with admin rights and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1   localcopy.tld
```

This will tell the system that this host should be handled by a local server.

Now find your `hhtpd-vhosts.conf` (it should be in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\` directory). Remove hashmark from line with

```
NameVirtualHost *.80
```

and insert the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/abc
  ServerName localcopy.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

This will tell Apache that when the request to handle `localcopy.tld` request, it should find the files in `C:/xampp/htdocs/abc` directory.

Finally you need to modify Apache main config file to allow Virtual Hosts.
Open the main Apache configuration file, `httpd.conf`, in a text editor. The file is located in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\`. Scroll down to the Supplemental configuration section at the end, and locate the following section (around line 500). Remove the hashmark which comments line:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

That should do it.

A more in depth explanation [is available here](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php).

All these will let you access your local copy at `http://localcopy.tld`.